# MKP DC-Link capacitor: Why Upp<0.2*Undc?

Tags: capacitor

In the data-sheet of polypropylene DC-Link capacitor (Vishay MKP1848 or Epcos B32778), I can read: "The peak-to-peak ripple voltage (Upp) shall not be greater than 0.2xUndc". Undc is max DC voltage.

Up to now I have assume that AC voltage could be 350Vrms for a 500V MKP capacitor if we assume a very clear and very safe sine voltage. In the reality, it is not the case, and a margin is necessary, like 900VDC for  household line use (other email list: with 240VAC in switzerland we have Upp=71%*Undc).

However the data-sheet of DC-Link MKP capacitor, they are more restrictive: the capacitor is design for DC voltage, and Upp (peak-2-peak) should be < 20%*Undc (VDC-max). So for 500V, we should not apply more than 35Vrms and always with the same voltage sign?

Polypropylene is non-polarized capacitor, so why such restriction for DC-Link?
Is there a risk to not strictly follow the data-sheet?
Where is the problem?

Comment: Some non polarised capacitors are designed not to handle AC. It's generally a compramise of capacitance vs ESR vs physical volume when making it. In this instance, I suspect that the ESR is too high for the capacitor to support the current required to fully charge and discharge it continuously. The clue is in the name - DC link capacitor.

Comment: ESR? maybe no. Check this one:

Comment: http://ch.farnell.com/fr-CH/vishay/mkp1848c71050jy5/condensateur-film-pp-100uf-500v/dp/2420020

Comment: ESR is 0.003 ohm, max current is 19A!

Answer (score 1):

DC-Link caps are designed to integrate the massive current pulses from voltage ripple and low Dissipation Factor, DF or it's equivalent ESR*Ipk^2*d.f. converted to RMS or using duty factor , d.f. of a pulse.

Historically capacitors have improved and presently, the figure of merit, that I use is

- T=ESR*C

  - to "ballpark" choose an appropriate cap.
- 100us~3ms Alum. electrolyte, general purpose , small to very large
- 0.5~10us Alum. electrolyte, ultra low low ESR
- 50~150ns Plastic, self healing , high voltage , lower values with higher V

This range will improve over time with R&D and nanotube processed surface on foil conductors.

Thus when you know Ic=C*dV/dt , the Vpp ripple has a direct relation to power dissipation

- Pd=I²*ESR

This ripple current without chokes or external resistance becomes inversely related to the ripple voltage but duty cycle also reduces so RMS Pd is constant.

- But if ripple voltage is too large then rms power self heating will damage the product and fail well before rated hours at elevated temperatures. ( highly stressed Arrhenius Effects or highly accelerated stress screen or HASS)

When high rms ripple current is expected consider 20% margin below rated spec. of the component.

> Bottom line is one uses large uF Alum caps for low frequency 100Hz and smaller value C plastic caps for SMPS off grid switcher at >=10kHz or step up using PFC when required for>100W in IEC std.

Comment: I should say that the current could be a limitation for capacitance value above about 100uF. But if we take this one:

Comment: http://ch.farnell.com/fr-CH/vishay/mkp1848-510-094k2/condensateur-film-pp-1uf-900v/dp/1791629

Comment: The value is 1uF. If I make the calculation, 240VAC/50Hz should give 73mA. Maximum RMS current is 2A. So with 240VAC, we use 3.6% of the max current!

Comment: what part of my explanation did you not understand?  what f, Vpp Vdc ripple do you want?

Comment: I continue my calculation: ESR is 0.063 ohm, so the dissipated power is 0.3mW. No risk of self-heating!

Comment: Same calculation with 100uF under 240VAC/50Hz: the current is 7.5A, and then the dissipated power is 0.17W. In principle, no risk of self-heating, right?

Comment: But I have an idea: Have they write the specification with highest AC frequency, like 10kHz? If they have do that, then I can understand why we cannot apply high AC voltage! If this hypothesis is correct, then I can assume that "APPLICATION NOTE AND LIMITING CONDITIONS" is not totally valid with 50Hz?

Comment: 10kHz is a test f not limit,,did you answer my questions? ripple voltage and Vdc

Comment: ripple voltage and Vdc. ... I expect 350Vdc 2A is 175Ω thus RC for 1uF= 175us and 50Hz rectified or 100Hz is 10ms so you need much greater C . I suggested 80ms for 10%Vripple or 35Vpp thus C=80ms/175Ω= 470uF

Comment: I think we are on two different schematics. You are talking about the decoupling of 350V/2A DC supply? I think you are right, >100uF is needed. In my case I was talking about filtering 240VAC/50Hz supply. My question is: is it possible to use the series MKP1848 for that? (that are called "DC-Link")

Comment: ............... no

Comment: I try to understand where is the limit, and maybe I have found an explanation in MKP1848 document: "These capacitors are not suitable for mains applications as across-the-line capacitors without additional protection. These  mains  applications  are  strictly  regulated  in  safety  standards  and  therefore  electromagnetic  interference  suppression  capacitors conforming the standards must be used."

Comment: ...So a sort of filtering (like EMI filter with X1/X2 capacitor) should be used first. After this filter MKP1848 could be used. Is it right?

Comment: Yes X caps with series choke in a PI configuration is a std Line filter. Some both CM and DM chokes in series for high power and better EMC

Comment: OK, I will do that. First a filter with X Caps in PI to remove EMI. After possibly MKP1848. Thank you!

Comment: no problem.. I'll send the bill for coffee and snacks